# simplemodal with jquery ajax()

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using a jquery ajax call to pull a file off my server and loading it into simplemodal for display. The input file is straight text with unix newlines "\n". I'm trying to convert the newlines to 
, or append a 
 to each line with no luck.

I've displayed the file as I want with the alert() function, but it looks like alert() does this conversion for me.

The modal displays the file - no problem. It's just not formatted the way I want. I've looked at many posts, and have tried a lot of things.

Any help is great. Thanks in advance. Mike

```
function getLogFile(filename) {
    jQuery('div').remove('.logfile-class');
    var logdiv = $(document.createElement('<div>')).attr({'id': 'logfile-id', 'class': 'logfile-class'});
    $('body').append(logdiv);

    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "./logs/" + filename,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(html) {
                    //alert(html);
                    html.replace(/\s$/g,"<br />");
                    $('#logfile-id').append(html);
                    $('#logfile-id').modal();
            }
    });

    $('.logfile-class').hide();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make your container a < pre >-Element and set the text using appendChild

```
html = "This\nis\na\ntest";
var element = document.getElementById("preElement");
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(html));
```

Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3mpy/9/)

Comment: Thanks. Using < pre > stipped out all newlines and gave me one long line. The suggested .replace modification didn't affect the content at all. Makes me wonder if the replace is working at all it it's position. Replacing the "\n" with "<br>" is what I'm after. It seems the replace I see in other posts for the same change is like the one you provided. Is this really how to get html newlines?

Comment: I see this working on jsfiddle but I can't make it work inside the success: section of the ajax function. I'll keep hacking on it, and post an update when I get it working. This seems so straight forward. Thanks again.

Comment: Remove the `html.replace` line and write `$('#logfile-id').append(document.createTextNode(html))`